# dc.js/crossfilter -> How to sort data in dc.js chart (like row) - Ascending x Descending

Tags: sorting, charts, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

How to sort data in dc.js chart (like row) - Ascending x Descending

I want to reorder the chart (row/column) by specified attribute (like 'avg' -> ascending)

I'm trying to use ".top()"... but unsuccessfully

Thanks

draft below
jsfiddle -> ewr5Z/2/

Answer (score 12):

You can use the ordering method:

```
        chart.ordering(function(d){ return -d.value })
```

If you write a custom reduce, you can have more flexibility:

```
        priceDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.part_number; });
        priceGroup = priceDimension.group().reduce(
            function (p, v) {
                ++p.count;
                p.sumPrice += v.price;
                p.avgPrice = p.sumPrice/p.count;
                return p;
            },
            function (p, v) {
                --p.count;
                p.sumPrice -= v.price;
                p.avgPrice = p.sumPrice/p.count;
                return p;
            },
            function () {
                return { count:0, sumPrice:0, avgPrice};
            });
    ....
    chart.ordering(function(d){ return d.value.avgPrice});
```

If you want the user to be able to change the sort order, you'd need to build a sort button that changes the ordering and rerenders the chart.

Comment: @nein, is there something special I need to do? I can't get it to be called on a row chart...

Comment: it does work in ver (1.7.5) but if you were like me and changed `value` to the name of the value in my case `sessions` like this  `.ordering(function(d){ return -d.sessions})` it doesn't work. If you just leave it as shown it does sort by the value (whatever the value's name)