# how to sort to get top 10 from "crossfilter-reduce-find-number-of-uniques"

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, dc.js

I am using codes from below to get unique counts..
[Crossfilter reduce :: find number of uniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239789/crossfilter-reduce-find-number-of-uniques)

I use ordering method found here "[dc.js/crossfilter -> How to sort data in dc.js chart (like row) - Ascending x Descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538336/dc-js-crossfilter-how-to-sort-data-in-dc-js-chart-like-row-ascending-x-de)".

When I show all the horizontal bars in row chart, ther are sorted in ascending/decending order. But when I tried to show only top 10, then the order is not by value but by alphabetic order of the group.

```
var donor=cf.dimension (function(d){ return d.donor;});

var donorCount=donor.group().reduce(
    function (p, d) {
        if (d.projectTitle in p.projectTitle)
            p.projectTitle[d.projectTitle]++;
        else {
            p.projectTitle[d.projectTitle] = 1;
            p.projectCount++;
        }
        return p;
    },

    function (p, d) {
        p.projectTitle[d.projectTitle]--;
        if (p.projectTitle[d.projectTitle] === 0) {
        delete p.projectTitle[d.projectTitle];
        p.projectCount--;
        }
        return p;
    },

    function () {
        return {
        projectCount: 0,
        projectTitle: {}
    };
});//this code is borrowed from http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/3LyhL/

.....
donorChart.width(320).height(600)
    .dimension(donor)
    .group(donorCount)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.projectCount;
    })//borrowed code
    .label(function(d){return "("+d.value.projectCount+")"+d.key;})
    .colorAccessor(function (d){return 1;})                   
    .elasticX(true)
    .ordering(function(d){ return -d.value.projectCount; })
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.top(10);
    });//this top ten code does not work as expected
```

without last three line of code, the chart show all the donor in sorted order by value. I am very new to javascript and cannot modify the last three line to get my work done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it just now.

```
donorChart.width(320).height(600)
.data(function (d) {
    return d.order(function (d) {
        return d.projectCount;
    }).top(10);
})
.ordering(function (d) {
    return -d.value.projectCount;
});
```

Comment: got a hit from crossfilter API reference

Answer (score 1):

You can set an ordering function on the group with [group.order](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-group_order).  The value returned from this accessor for each row will determine the order of the rows when the top N is taken.  [group.top](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-group_top) will return the top rows in descending order by this value.

In your case you could try this to see if it works:

```
    donorCount.order(function(d) { return d.projectCount; });
```

Unfortunately I don't know how dc.js retrieves the groups. If it uses `group.top` then this should work.  If it uses `group.all` the it won't because the docs say `group.all` always uses natural ordering.

Comment: Thanks. I have exactly the same code you advised but removed in this post as it does not work as expected. It still keep natural order. <br />Only  donorChart.ordering(function(d){ return -d.value.projectCount; }) sorted by value but it seems overridden when i add group.top(10) code. The sorting goes back to natural order (alphabetic) again.